# Seat of My Pants

Tags: idioms

I was told that I live my life by the seat of my pants, and though it doesn't sound like a compliment, I'm not sure that it is an insult either.  What is the derivation of "seat of my pants"?

Comment: Have you checked any online dictionary to find out what this phrase means?

Answer (score 2):

Taken from [The Phrase Finder](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/139400.html):

> This is **early aviation parlance**. Aircraft initially had few navigation aids and flying was accomplished by means of the pilot's judgment. The term emerged in the **1930s** and was first widely used in reports of Douglas Corrigan's flight from the USA to Ireland in 1938.
>
> That flight was reported in many US newspapers of the day, including this piece, titled 'Corrigan Flies By The Seat Of His Pants', in The Edwardsville Intelligencer, 19th July 1938:
>
> *"Douglas Corrigan was described as an aviator 'who flies by the seat of his pants' today by a mechanic who helped him rejuvinate the plane which airport men have now nicknamed the 'Spirit of $69.90'. The old flying expression of 'flies by the seat of his trousers' was explained by Larry Conner, means going aloft without instruments, radio or other such luxuries."*
>
> The 'old flying expression' quoted above (although it can't have been very old in 1938) that refers to trousers rather than pants does suggest that the phrase was **originally British** and crossed the Atlantic prior to becoming 'by the seat of one's pants'.

Emphasis mine.